# Declaration and memory allocation to target parameter in copy_from_user call

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel, malloc, allocation

I have a pointer to a data buffer in user space mode, and now I want to copy the value of that data to kernel mode with "copy_from_user" function.

Assume that my data pointer is "data.ptr.buffer" and it's size is "data_size". the declaration of "data.ptr.buffer" is : `const void    *buffer;`

Now, how I can declare and allocate memory to it in kernel mode to get data buffer value in kernel mode? my "copy_from_user" call is something like :

`copy_from_user(data_value, data.ptr.buffer, data_size)`

In other words I want to know how I can declare data_value parameter and allocate memory to it (e.g kzalloc,...)?

Comment: You may want to look into `kmalloc()` which is the right thing to use if you just want some *arbitrary memory*.

Answer (score 0):

if you know your data size is small, say, a 100 byte, you could declare a char array.
usigned char kernel_cmd_buf[129];